# Windows Forms checkboxes with LINQ

Tags: winforms, linq, checkedlistbox

I am using checkedListBox with windows forms . I am using LINQ for database operations.

Now when user edits the form I need to see if checkboxes are new selected and if entry does not exist insert to the table.If they had checked it before and now they checked it off I need to delete that entry from database. Can some one help me how can I do this in LINQ some easy way ? In sort I need to Insert any newly selected checkboxes and delete if they existed before but are not checked off.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there any button to submit changes or after each selection changes will be submitted?

Comment: Yes its a long form . Button saves changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily get the checked and unchecked items, but to determine if they are originally checked/unchecked, you have to store that somewhere, whether the tag property or in a variable somewhere.

HTH.